# Generate legends for each bubble in amcharts v4

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I am trying to create a bubble chart using amCharts Version 4 library. Each bubble here represent a different country having different color. Now I need to generate legends for each bubble present in the chart. I am not able to achieve the same. Can anyone help me for it.

I am using the below mentioned tutorial to create the bubble chart.

[https://www.amcharts.com/demos/zoomable-bubble-chart](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/zoomable-bubble-chart/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/legend/#Adding_custom_items) you could use custom data for your legend.

```
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.legend.data = [{
  "name": "2016",
  "fill":"#72A6B2"
}, {
  "name": "2017",
  "fill": "#667E93"
}, {
  "name": "2018",
  "fill": "#488BB2"
}];
```

To adapt this to your data and create a legend for all countries you could use the following snippet:

```
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.legend.data = chart.data.map(i => ({
  "name": i.title, 
  "fill": i.color
}));
```

To update the data on legend toggle you can add a hidden property on your data values and tell amcharts to use it to hide some bullets.

```
series.dataFields.hidden = "hidden";
```

Add the data id to the legend data and the hidden property if you want to hide some countries on init.

```
chart.legend.data = chart.data.map(i => ({
  id: i.id, 
  name: i.title, 
  fill: i.color,
  visible: !i.hidden
}));
```

Add an click event to the legend to update the chart. Use the `"up"` event, because `event.target.isActive` is updated after the `"hit"` event is called.

```
chart.legend.itemContainers.template.events.on("up", (event) => {
  const id = event.target.dataItem.dataContext.id;
  chart.data.find(i => i.id === id).hidden = !event.target.isActive;
  chart.validateData();
});
```

I created [this code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZPYMGV) as reference.

Comment: I already tried this code, this will generate legends for the chart, but the events won't work with these legends e.g. clicking on a country legend won't enable/disable the bubble for that particular country.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I updated my answer and the code pen and added an approach which could solve your problem. Your can use the hidden property and update it on legend item state change. Hope it works for you.